# Resultado Inesperado em SELECT

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, select

Tenho um SELECT que faz join em três tabelas, pegando os dados do pedido, cliente que pediu, assistente responsável e valores relacionados aos pedidos.

todos os `Clientes` e `Assistentes` duplicados nessa `query` estão retornando como `NULL`, no caso queria que os nomes deles mostrassem

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT pedido.id,pedido.local,pedido.data_hora,pedido.status,cliente.nome as nomeCliente,assistente.nome as nomeAssistente,pagamento.valor_bruto,pagamento.valor_liquido,pagamento.imposto
FROM pedido LEFT JOIN pagamento
ON pedido.id = pagamento.pedido_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN assistente
ON pedido.id = assistente.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cliente
ON pedido.id = cliente.id
ORDER BY pedido.id;
```

**Output:**

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------+
| id | local                                                                      | data_hora           | status | nomeCliente              | nomeAssistente         | valor_bruto | valor_liquido | imposto |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------+
|  1 | Avenida do Contorno                                                        | 2016-06-25 19:38:00 |      1 | Janaina de Araujo Amaral | Alberto Fonseca Araujo |       39.65 |         29.65 |      10 |
|  2 | Rua Portugal                                                               | 2016-05-30 14:54:00 |      1 | Felipe Almeida           | Juliana Campos         |        25.4 |          15.4 |      10 |
|  3 | Rua Dido                                                                   | 2016-05-25 10:34:00 |      1 | Mariana Ferreira         | Mauro Fernandes Pinto  |          12 |             2 |      10 |
|  4 | Avenida Engenheiros                                                        | 2016-03-12 08:16:00 |      1 | Marcello Lessa           | Fátima Veras de Souza  |       54.28 |         44.28 |      10 |
|  5 | R. Santa Cruz, 546 - GrajaÃº, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30431-228, Brasil       | 2016-09-18 00:54:00 |      1 | JÃ¡donos Fieslorbe       | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
|  6 | R. Santa Cruz, 546 - GrajaÃº, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30431-228, Brasil       | 2016-09-18 00:55:57 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
|  7 | R. Marechal Hermes, 494-496 - Gutierrez, Belo Horizonte - MG, Brasil       | 2016-09-18 00:56:22 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
|  8 | R. Fagundes Varela, 135 - Lagoinha, Belo Horizonte - MG, 31210-310, Brasil | 2016-09-18 02:52:32 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
|  9 | R. Santa Cruz, 546 - GrajaÃº, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30431-228, Brasil       | 2016-09-18 08:28:06 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
| 10 |                                                                            | 2016-09-18 08:55:54 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
| 11 |                                                                            | 2016-09-18 08:56:00 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
| 12 | Rua Um, 54 - Conj. Confisco, Belo Horizonte - MG, 31360-480, Brasil        | 2016-09-18 08:58:41 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
| 13 | R. Rio Negro, 1357-1565 - GrajaÃº, Belo Horizonte - MG, 30431-115, Brasil  | 2016-09-18 10:10:40 |      1 | NULL                     | NULL                   |        NULL |          NULL |    NULL |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: `ON pedido.id = assistente.id` e `ON pedido.id = cliente.id` estão corretos? não seria `ON pedido.assistente_id = assistente.id` e `ON pedido.cliente_id = cliente.id` ?

Comment: @ÉdipoCostaRebouças Putz. Era isso mesmo, estava a umas meia hora tentando achar um erro bobo desse, Vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coluna da tabela pedido usada no join com a tabela cliente deveria ser o id do cliente, por exemplo pedido.cliente_id, e não o id do pedido. O mesmo acontece no join com a tabela assistente